# Can't access SharePoint 2010 site from SharePoint Designer 2010 from Windows7 machine

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When i am trying to access my SharePoint site from the SharePoint Designer 2010, i am getting the following error message: "Server error: The version of Microsoft SharePoint Foundation running on the server is more recent than the version of SharePoint Designer you are using. You need a more recent version of SharePoint Designer."

I have Windows7-32bit machine,
Installed MS SharePoint Designer 2010 -32bit,
My SharePoint site URL format Example: https://test.site.com/sites/Quality

Note: This site is opening in the browser without any issues.

Some times i am getting this error also: "The server could not complete your request.
For more specific information, click the Details button."

Please suggest me if you have any ideas.

Comment: What version and patch level is your SharePoint site?

Comment: Make sure you are using Internet Explorer.  The "open with Sharepoint Designer" buttons in the ribbon don't work right in Firefox, you know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, this worked for me...

1) Reset IIS in the Server

if this doesn't work then

2) Restart the Server and check for any updates pending to be updated in the server.

Thanks,

Prasath

Answer (score 0):

SP1 installed on server but not for office?